# How to refresh after updating core data value in table view cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I'm using core data in my app.I have an two view controller one viewcontroller show the list of book names after selecting anyone of the book move to second view controller for using the update button to update the value as 1 that will be show in core data table.Now back to main viewcontroller and after selecting same book doesnot show the value in secondviewcontroller but core data table having a value as 1. how to reload main viewcontroller in table view with core data table value .plz anyone known help me.

Here the source code below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  if(dictionary!=nil)//net is not connected fetch core data to display the booknames
  {
     UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@" Warning Message" message:@"You are not connect to internet so becoz of loading default values" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
     [alert show];
     [self fetchValueFromDatabase];

  }      

}

-(void)fetchValueFromDatabase
{

 NSFetchRequest *fech=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
 NSEntityDescription *entity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Bookname" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
 [fech setEntity:entity];
 NSError *savingError=nil;
 NSArray *allBook=[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fech error:&savingError];

 NSLog(@"Array count value:%i",allBook.count);

 coreBookName=[allBook valueForKey:@"bookName"];
 NSLog(@"all value:%@",coreBookName);

 for(NSString *key in coreBookName)
 {
     NSLog(@"Key value:%@",key);  

    [insertBookname addObject:key];
 }

 coreVoteCount=[allBook valueForKey:@"vote"];
 NSLog(@"All vote value:%@",coreVoteCount);
 for(NSString *key in coreVoteCount)
 {
    [bookCount addObject:key];
    NSLog(@"Key value:%@",key);
 }

 for(NSArray *key in allBook)
 {
     [addItems addObject:key];
     NSLog(@"All items:%@",key);
 }
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.tableview1 reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call your below method from (void)viewWillAppear:method

```
[self fetchValueFromDatabase];//call this from ViewWillAppear
```

Let me know it is working or not...

Happy Coding.!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling this in viewDidLoad   **[self fetchValueFromDatabase];** and  **[self.tableview1 reloadData];** this in viewWillAppear that is why you are not getting any updates in your table.

What you should do is call **[self.tableview1 reloadData];** at the end of your function **fetchValueFromDatabase**

```
-(void)fetchValueFromDatabase
{

 NSFetchRequest *fech=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
 NSEntityDescription *entity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Bookname"  inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
 [fech setEntity:entity];
 NSError *savingError=nil;
 ........................
 .......................

 .......................

 [self.tableview1 reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Can't reload data.Stop the simulator and then again run the simulator it will retrieve value from core data table.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or crash, do as I said. But first check are you using same Array which you are updating from coredata to populate the table, if yes then NSLog your array to make sure its not empty before calling reloadData on your table.

Comment: No errors.The NSLog only prints oldest core data table value what can i do

Comment: That means your core data is not having new data, to test if everything is going fine, before calling fetchValueFromDatabase add a dummy data in your coredata and then proceed as I told you, and also put some NSLogs in your table Delegate numberOfRowsInSection, hope you are setting rows according to your Array of data you updating.

Comment: If your table reloads with new dummy data every then everything is fine and also make sure you are settings the delegates and datasources to self of table